# XNA Collision Detection in Platformer

Tags: xna, 2d, collision-detection

I've been working on a simple 2D platformer engine. So far I've got a sprite moving around (not yet animated), and 3 platforms for a "Jetpac" type game (old ZX Spectrum game - I'm sure if you google it you can play it in a flash box).

Now I'm onto the problem of implementing collision detection so the sprite can actually walk on the platforms. I think this will be the biggest job and then it's quite easy to continue. But how to implement collision detection with platforms?!

I have bounding boxes for all platforms, as well as the character, and later on there will be bounding boxes for enemy sprites, but that can be handled later. Basically, what is the easiest way to allow a sprite to walk on a platform, and not go through it using Bounding Box?

A bit more information:

- Character class controls drawing the sprite and updating the sprite using a Vector2 position variable, updated with a Vector2 motion variable.
- A Platform class controls the drawing of the platforms (there are 3), so plat1, plat2 and plat3 are all types of Platform.
- The platforms need to be fully solid on all sides, but allow the sprite to walk on.

Any help?

Comment: Are - it's a great game, but very overlooked and underrated.

Comment: I see there's no answers yet. You can always try posting at gamedev if it stays that way.

Comment: Did you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227888/xna-c-2d-platformer-game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Basics for simple collision detection with rectangles:**

Use the [rectangle struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx) for your bounding boxes. You can then use the [intersects method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx) to compare your platform bounding boxes to your character bounding box.

**Basics for maintaining performance:**

If you have large levels with a lot of platforms your game might get slow if you compare all your platforms with the character. You can for example use the [axis aligned bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_bounding_box) technique to avoid this. The basics of AABB is that you sort your bounding boxes along the x and y axis and therefore will get an aproximate location of the BBs.

**Last but not least:**

Look at the [platformer tutorial](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/platformer).

Comment: I have looked into the intersects method, but I need a bit of help figuring out what the : `if (character.bounds.intersects(plat1.bounds) { //do something }` what would the //do something be?

Comment: Basically, if the character is moving and suddenly intersects with something, stop it from moving. You shouldn't expect a complete solution here, since you're the developer. I really recommend the platformer tutorial though.

Comment: I have tried this so far:
`            if (player.characterBounds.Intersects(plat1.platformBounds))
            {
                player.motion.Y = 0;
                collision = true;
            }
            else collision = false;
            
            player.Update(collision); `
But it still does nothing..I wonder if this will help to give a tip?

Comment: Hm its not _that_ easy. First of all, it's not enough to just set the motion of the player to zero, since collision already occured which means that you have to solve that collision by going one step back. 
Or to put it into other words, calculate the new position of the player first, then check if there is collision, and then decide if you want to apply the new position to the player or not, depending if collision was detected or not. 
Also, what i see in the code is, that you are not resetting the motion of the player when there is no collision, so the player probably won't move...

Comment: I've solved part of the problem - I wasn't updating the characterBounds, but now it's recognising collision. Just have to correct the position of the player so he's not half way into the platform now! Also I didn't post the player.Update procedure, which updated the .X motion, so the player could move left and right, but not vertically, which is the idea

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the option of using a physics engine in your game? For a simple platformer this might be overkill, but you can easily add additional physical effects.

2D physics engines I can advise you to look into are:

- Box2D, which has a native XNA port (see [here](http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/))
- Chipmunk, which once had a port to XNA, but it seems to have gone missing.

Comment: I don't really want to use a physics engine - I want to program as much of it myself as I can, and this is really the only thing that I have no clue about, but it's one of the biggest things